# Opentok Session fail

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, parse-platform, opentok

I am going to implement video chat using Opentok by following the post http://www.iphonegamezone.net/ios-tutorial-create-iphone-video-chat-app-using-parse-and-opentok-tokbox/

I have implemented parse.com for the backend which is responsible for session and token creation for opentok

When I am running the code, It creates SessionId,active users (Which I can see in the parse.com's backend)

But When I am trying to connect to opentok with help of following code, Error message coming stating that "The Session failed to connect"

```
_session = [[OTSession alloc] initWithSessionId:sessionID
                                       delegate:self];
[_session addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"connectionCount"
              options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew
              context:nil];
[_session connectWithApiKey:kApiKey token:token];
```

if any one know how to solve this problem then help.
Or any suggestion also appreciated.

Comment: I'm facing a similar problem with this project. Any idea how to fix it? The video stream never initiates.

Comment: I have mentioned the solution worked for me. please check your firewall (internet) may block to use, can ask to network admin to allow it.

Comment: I just tested on my home network (no firewall). The connection between the two devices is initiated but the video stream is never presented. Any thoughts?

Comment: If it's not a big deal, can you quickly try downloading the project form that site and running it against ios 9? It seems the delegate method streamCreated is never called...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes,Now I got the solution.

Firewall was not allowing me before to connect the session.
I allowed the firewall connection by providing network ID and password.

Now It is working for me.